# Making this query faster

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

So as I mentioned previously I don't deal with raw SQL that often so need help enhancing this query. Currently, it takes around 3 seconds. I wonder if their a way to make it better. I removed some selects to make the query smaller.

```
select row_number() over ()                      as id,
       scope.id                                  as sow_id,
       scope.*,
       task.*,
       po.entity_id                              as group_name
from t_scope_of_work as scope,
     (select * from audittaskimpl) as task
         Left join peopleassignments_potowners po ON task.taskid = po.task_id and po.entity_id like '%/%'
Where task.processinstanceid IN
      (select distinct processinstanceid from taskvariableimpl where value = scope.sownumber)
order by task.processinstanceid desc, task.createdon desc;
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Sort  (cost=3037398.97..3037728.28 rows=131726 width=1981) (actual time=1714.744..1714.812 rows=648 loops=1)                                                                     |
|  Sort Key: task.processinstanceid DESC, task.createdon DESC                                                                                                                     |
|  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 884kB                                                                                                                                          |
|  Buffers: shared hit=930703                                                                                                                                                     |
|  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.55..2800174.53 rows=131726 width=1981) (actual time=6.919..1713.339 rows=648 loops=1)                                                                   |
|        Buffers: shared hit=930703                                                                                                                                               |
|        ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=0.55..2798527.96 rows=131726 width=1965) (actual time=6.905..1712.235 rows=648 loops=1)                                                      |
|              Merge Cond: (po.task_id = task.taskid)                                                                                                                             |
|              Buffers: shared hit=930703                                                                                                                                         |
|              ->  Index Only Scan using idx_paspot_taskentity on peopleassignments_potowners po  (cost=0.27..32.45 rows=462 width=28) (actual time=0.101..0.378 rows=446 loops=1)|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, first I would do an explain analyze on it, so that you have a resonable estimate on what the database is acutally doing with it.

Comment: Do you get a performance improvement by replacing the WHERE ... IN with an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Folks over https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help as well

Comment: Won't make a difference, but: `(select * from audittaskimpl) as task` can be simplified to `audittaskimpl as task`. And please do not mix the old, ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause and explicit `JOIN` operators. Use explicit `JOIN` for all joins

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query boils down to:

```
select row_number() over ()                      as id,
       scope.id                                  as sow_id,
       scope.*,
       task.*,
       po.entity_id                              as group_name
from t_scope_of_work as scope
join audittaskimpl as task
  on task.processinstanceid IN  (select distinct tvi.processinstanceid 
                                   from taskvariableimpl tvi
                                  where tvi.value = scope.sownumber)
Left outer join peopleassignments_potowners po 
             ON po.task_id = task.taskid 
            and po.entity_id like '%/%'

order by task.processinstanceid desc, task.createdon desc;
```

Without an explain it's pretty much impossible to advise on where the bottlenecks are in this query. E.g. you might be missing some indexes, it might be there simply is too much data to ever get this fast.

That said, I doubt you need the `distinct` in there; in fact, it might be worth trying an `EXISTS()` construction simply to see what that gives.
Something like this:

```
 select row_number() over ()                      as id,
       scope.id                                  as sow_id,
       scope.*,
       task.*,
       po.entity_id                              as group_name
from t_scope_of_work as scope
join audittaskimpl as task
  on exists ( select * 
                from taskvariableimpl tvi
               where tvi.value             = scope.sownumber
                 and tvi.processinstanceid = task.processinstanceid )
Left outer join peopleassignments_potowners po 
             ON po.task_id = task.taskid 
            and po.entity_id like '%/%'

order by task.processinstanceid desc, task.createdon desc;
```

Warning: try before you buy! It could be this turns out to be working WORSE than your original query, I've never done a `JOIN [..] ON EXISTS()` before; again, without proper knowledge of your tables, volumes, indexes, data layout (read: are there many 'hits' in the joins or only a few records?), etc... we're pretty much working blind here.

Comment: This is pretty amazing, Not sure how you did it but looks like it came from 2-3 seconds to 300 ms.